# Are references needed for facts that we all learn as children aged 1-2?

Tags: discussion, flagging, references

Are [references needed](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/79171/32077) for any of the following facts that we all learn as children aged 1-2:

- Cubes don't roll
- Spheres roll
- Gravity makes spheres roll on slopes
- Gravity doesn't make spheres roll on the flat
- Things which roll are prone to not being where they started out
- Indicating some location requires that you don't indicate some different location instead.
- Absorption takes place at the surface

Surely an answer which is just a statement of facts which are in themselves self-evident, requires no references.

Or is that just an automated flag that appeared for illogical reasons?

Answer (score 3):

I placed that banner because you make 2 unsupported claims:

- > ...it's worth pointing out that a cube with rounded corners and edges has larger surface area to volume ratio than a spherical dropping, **making it more efficient for the reabsorbtion of moisture**, which would be an **evolutionary advantage** in a place where water is in short supply....

And

- > Additionally, in respect of the claim made here that droppings are used for marking, it **may be advantageous to have a dropping that doesn't roll**, if it's important some subsequent visitor can identify the precise spot the droppings were dropped, especially if one inhabits sloped terrain (which a wombat does - mountainous areas of Australia)...

These unsubstantiated claims are opinions or 'hunches', rather than being evidence-based.

Plus, a 2-year old doesn't know what absorption is, let alone that

> Absor[p]tion takes place at the surface :)

Comment: Nonsense. Absorption takes place at the surface and therefore a larger surface area increases rate of absorption...think lungs, gills, intestines. This is junior school physics and should be self-evident to any scientist. As is the fact that reducing water loss is an evolutionary advantage in dry climates. And again, the fact that things which roll make poor place markers on slopes, is self-evident and requires no reference.

Comment: @RobertFrost all true, but your choice of words (*would be*, *may be*) testifies your answer is *your opinion*, hence the banner. An educated hunch is still just a hunch.

Comment: I'll be frank with yo. To me this banner screams 'it hurts my ego sometimes that a superior command of basic reasoning, sometimes trump's years of study.'

Comment: NO. There is no opinion here. This is well-reasoned argument based upon rudimentary scientific facts.

Comment: Whatever you call it, a hunch, a thought, nonsense or argument, it's unreferenced.

Comment: @RobertFrost and don't take it personal[ly] :)

Comment: Don't worry, I won't take it personal[ly] ;)